# Hide parent <li> when all child <li> are hidden

Tags: jquery

I have a page that will hide list elements based on a filter input. So far I have it hiding the child elements, but what I am trying to do is also hide the parent element when all of the children for that parent are hidden. I am having a difficult time figuring out how to modify the parent style based on the children.

```js
     $('.filterinput').keyup(function() {


         var a = $(this).val();
         if (a.length >= 2) {

             var containing = $('#list li').filter(function() {
                 var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + a, 'i');
                 return regex.test($('a', this).text());
             }).slideDown();
             $('#list li').not(containing).slideUp();


         } else {
             $('#list li').slideDown();
             $("#groupList li").each(function() {
                 $(this).show();
             })
         }
         return false;
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6">
   <label class="control-label">Filter Tests</label><br/>
   <input class="filterinput" type="text" style="width:100%;">
</div>
<div id "panelGroups">
   <ul id="groupList">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="allergy_panels">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Allergy Panels" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Allergy Panels</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-allergy_panels" id="list">
                  <li class="liChild-allergy_panels"><a id="Area 10 (TX/OK)" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Area 10 (TX/OK)</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-allergy_panels"><a id="Total IgE seperate" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Total IgE seperate</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-allergy_panels"><a id="Basic Food Allergy" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Basic Food Allergy</a></li>
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="arthritis_panel">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Arthritis Panel" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Arthritis Panel</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-arthritis_panel" id="list">
                  <li class="liChild-arthritis_panel"><a id="RF" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">RF</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-arthritis_panel"><a id="CRP" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">CRP</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-arthritis_panel"><a id="CBC" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">CBC</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-arthritis_panel"><a id="Uric Acid" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Uric Acid</a></li>
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="diabetic_profile">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Diabetic Profile" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Diabetic Profile</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-diabetic_profile" id="list">
                  <li class="liChild-diabetic_profile"><a id="HgbA1c (1EDTA)" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">HgbA1c (1EDTA)</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-diabetic_profile"><a id="C-peptide" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">C-peptide</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-diabetic_profile"><a id="Insulin" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Insulin</a></li>
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="female_hormone">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Female Hormone" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Female Hormone</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-female_hormone" id="list">
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="Testosterone(Total)" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Testosterone(Total)</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="Intact PTH" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Intact PTH</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="Cortisol" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Cortisol</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="hCG (female)" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">hCG (female)</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="SHBG" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">SHBG</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="LH (female)" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">LH (female)</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="DHEA-S" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">DHEA-S</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="Anti-TPO" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Anti-TPO</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="FSH" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">FSH</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="Progesterone" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Progesterone</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="Estradiol" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Estradiol</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="Testerone(Free)" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Testerone(Free)</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="CBC w/Diff (1EDTA)" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">CBC w/Diff (1EDTA)</a></li>
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="heart_health">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Heart Health" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Heart Health</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-heart_health" id="list">
                  <li class="liChild-heart_health"><a id="CRPhs" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">CRPhs</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-heart_health"><a id="CK" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">CK</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-heart_health"><a id="LDL(Direct)" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">LDL(Direct)</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-heart_health"><a id="Cholesterol" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Cholesterol</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-heart_health"><a id="Triglycerides" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Triglycerides</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-heart_health"><a id="HDL" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">HDL</a></li>
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="hepatitis">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Hepatitis" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Hepatitis</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-hepatitis" id="list">
                  <li class="liChild-hepatitis"><a id="HCV" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">HCV</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-hepatitis"><a id="Anti-hBs Quantitative" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Anti-hBs Quantitative</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-hepatitis"><a id="HAV Total" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">HAV Total</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-hepatitis"><a id="HBsAg" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">HBsAg</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-hepatitis"><a id="HBcAb IgM" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">HBcAb IgM</a></li>
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="immunology">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Immunology" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Immunology</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-immunology" id="list">
                  <li class="liChild-immunology"><a id="CA153" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">CA153</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-immunology"><a id="CA125" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">CA125</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-immunology"><a id="C3" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">C3</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-immunology"><a id="C4" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">C4</a></li>
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="metabolic_health">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Metabolic Health" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Metabolic Health</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-metabolic_health" id="list">
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="nutritional_health">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Nutritional Health" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Nutritional Health</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-nutritional_health" id="list">
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="pre-natal">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Pre-Natal" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Pre-Natal</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-pre-natal" id="list">
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="pre_surgical">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Pre Surgical" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Pre Surgical</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-pre_surgical" id="list">
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="post_surgical">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Post Surgical" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Post Surgical</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-post_surgical" id="list">
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="std_profile">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="STD Profile" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">STD Profile</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-std_profile" id="list">
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="thyroid">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Thyroid" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Thyroid</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-thyroid" id="list">
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="weight_loss">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Weight Loss" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Weight Loss</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-weight_loss" id="list">
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="send_out_test">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Send Out Test" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Send Out Test</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-send_out_test" id="list">
                  <li class="liChild-send_out_test"><a id="AFP Maternal" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">AFP Maternal</a></li>
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still a little bit raw so it could use some refactoring for efficiency but hopefully it will light up the invisible bulb over your head. Try adding:

```
'slow', function(){
    if($(this).parent().children('li:visible').length === 0)
        $(this).parent().parent().slideUp();
    else $(this).parent().parent().slideDown();
}
```

as the first two params in `slideUp()` so it runs as a callback, `'slow'` is just there to BE the first param.

Note: there are some empty entries in your sample (*Metabolic Health*, *Nutritional Health*, etc) which won't be affected by this code, I left it so thinking there won't be empty entries in your real data sets.

HIH

```js
$('.filterinput').keyup(function() {
    var a = $(this).val();
    if (a.length >= 2) {
        var containing = $('#list li').filter(function() {
            var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + a, 'i');
            return regex.test($('a', this).text());
        }).slideDown();
        
        $('#list li').not(containing).slideUp('slow', function(){
            if($(this).parent().children('li:visible').length === 0)
                $(this).parent().parent().slideUp();
              else $(this).parent().parent().slideDown();
          });
        
    } else {
        $('#list li').slideDown();
        $("#groupList li").each(function() {
            $(this).show();
        })
    }
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6">
   <label class="control-label">Filter Tests</label><br/>
   <input class="filterinput" type="text" style="width:100%;">
</div>
<div id "panelGroups">
   <ul id="groupList">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="allergy_panels">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Allergy Panels" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Allergy Panels</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-allergy_panels" id="list">
                  <li class="liChild-allergy_panels"><a id="Area 10 (TX/OK)" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Area 10 (TX/OK)</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-allergy_panels"><a id="Total IgE seperate" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Total IgE seperate</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-allergy_panels"><a id="Basic Food Allergy" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Basic Food Allergy</a></li>
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="arthritis_panel">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Arthritis Panel" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Arthritis Panel</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-arthritis_panel" id="list">
                  <li class="liChild-arthritis_panel"><a id="RF" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">RF</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-arthritis_panel"><a id="CRP" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">CRP</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-arthritis_panel"><a id="CBC" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">CBC</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-arthritis_panel"><a id="Uric Acid" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Uric Acid</a></li>
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="diabetic_profile">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Diabetic Profile" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Diabetic Profile</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-diabetic_profile" id="list">
                  <li class="liChild-diabetic_profile"><a id="HgbA1c (1EDTA)" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">HgbA1c (1EDTA)</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-diabetic_profile"><a id="C-peptide" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">C-peptide</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-diabetic_profile"><a id="Insulin" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Insulin</a></li>
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="female_hormone">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Female Hormone" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Female Hormone</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-female_hormone" id="list">
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="Testosterone(Total)" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Testosterone(Total)</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="Intact PTH" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Intact PTH</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="Cortisol" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Cortisol</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="hCG (female)" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">hCG (female)</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="SHBG" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">SHBG</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="LH (female)" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">LH (female)</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="DHEA-S" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">DHEA-S</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="Anti-TPO" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Anti-TPO</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="FSH" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">FSH</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="Progesterone" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Progesterone</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="Estradiol" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Estradiol</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="Testerone(Free)" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Testerone(Free)</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-female_hormone"><a id="CBC w/Diff (1EDTA)" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">CBC w/Diff (1EDTA)</a></li>
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="heart_health">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Heart Health" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Heart Health</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-heart_health" id="list">
                  <li class="liChild-heart_health"><a id="CRPhs" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">CRPhs</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-heart_health"><a id="CK" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">CK</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-heart_health"><a id="LDL(Direct)" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">LDL(Direct)</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-heart_health"><a id="Cholesterol" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Cholesterol</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-heart_health"><a id="Triglycerides" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Triglycerides</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-heart_health"><a id="HDL" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">HDL</a></li>
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="hepatitis">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Hepatitis" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Hepatitis</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-hepatitis" id="list">
                  <li class="liChild-hepatitis"><a id="HCV" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">HCV</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-hepatitis"><a id="Anti-hBs Quantitative" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Anti-hBs Quantitative</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-hepatitis"><a id="HAV Total" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">HAV Total</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-hepatitis"><a id="HBsAg" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">HBsAg</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-hepatitis"><a id="HBcAb IgM" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">HBcAb IgM</a></li>
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="immunology">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Immunology" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Immunology</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-immunology" id="list">
                  <li class="liChild-immunology"><a id="CA153" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">CA153</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-immunology"><a id="CA125" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">CA125</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-immunology"><a id="C3" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">C3</a></li>
                  <li class="liChild-immunology"><a id="C4" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">C4</a></li>
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="metabolic_health">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Metabolic Health" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Metabolic Health</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-metabolic_health" id="list">
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="nutritional_health">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Nutritional Health" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Nutritional Health</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-nutritional_health" id="list">
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="pre-natal">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Pre-Natal" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Pre-Natal</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-pre-natal" id="list">
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="pre_surgical">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Pre Surgical" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Pre Surgical</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-pre_surgical" id="list">
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="post_surgical">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Post Surgical" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Post Surgical</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-post_surgical" id="list">
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="std_profile">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="STD Profile" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">STD Profile</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-std_profile" id="list">
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="thyroid">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Thyroid" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Thyroid</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-thyroid" id="list">
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="weight_loss">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Weight Loss" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Weight Loss</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-weight_loss" id="list">
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <li class="send_out_test">
               <a style="color:blue; font-size: large;" id="Send Out Test" onCLick="reply_click(this.id)">Send Out Test</a>
               <ul class="ulChild-send_out_test" id="list">
                  <li class="liChild-send_out_test"><a id="AFP Maternal" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">AFP Maternal</a></li>
                  <hr>
                  <br/><br/>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great. The html is actually generated from a set of queries, so the empty parents I removed by just excluding them. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a if statement to check if all children are hidden then hide the parent, maybe something like:

```
if (!$(child1, child2, child3).is(":visible")){
   $(parent).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested*

```
    <ul id='sporks'>
      <li>0</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>

    <script>
      $sporks    = $('sporks')

      $sporks_li = $sporks.find('li')

      $sporks_li.each(function(li,index){

        $(li).on('click',function(e){

          $(this).addClass('hidden')

          var hide_parrent = true


          var li_array = $sporks_li.toArray()

          for(var x; x< li_array.length;x++ ){
            if( ! $(li_array[x]).hasClass('hidden')){
            hide_parrent = false
            break
            }   
          }   

          if(hide_parrent){
            $sporks_li.addClass('hidden')
            // other things like say reopen children
          }   

        })  

      })  
    </script>
```